# Excel IF function with multiple conditions/outcomes

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

How would this be written as a nested IF function:

```
If single
  a. give <20 = "Bachelor"
  b. give >20 = "Big Donor"
If married**
  a. give <20 = "Frugal Double"
  b. give >20 = "Charity Couple"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
= IF(A2="Single",IF(C2<20,"Bachelor","Big Donor"),IF(C2<20,"Frugal Double","Charity Couple"))
```

where A2 could have "Single" or other value (add other validation if needed)
and C2 could have any number as a value (add other validation if necessary)

Hope that will help